# How can I use an external ssl link in my laravel application?

Tags: laravel, server

I want to call a ssl link in my code into laravel . invoking this link sometimes does not reurn  any responses. Is there any limits on the server?
and this is my code ::

$url = "https://185.109.251.240:22498/api/v1/dialout/clicktodial.php?session_id=$sessionId&number1=$userMobile&number2=$adviserMobile&maxduration=$maxDurationToMs";

```
$client = new Client();

    try {
        $res = $client->request('GET', "$url",
            [
                'verify'=>false
            ]
        );

        return response()->json(['success'=>$call]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$call]);
    }
```